# How to check misspelled words using Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, grammar

I am trying to use the "Check spelling and grammar" feature provided by Texmaker. When I run it instead of getting the misspelled words I get a ton of weird symbols that look something like this:

[image]

I need to specify that I would like to check a text written in Italian and I have no idea on how to do it. 
My questions is simple: what should I do in order to check misspelled words on an Italian text by using Texmaker?

Comment: In Options > Configure Texmaker > Editor > some like  `/usr/share/myspell/dicts/it-IT.dic`. Check that the file is here. Have you installed/reinstalled `myspell-it`?

Comment: I have installed myspell-it and the configurations are just like you wrote... but I still get the same symbols and no correction at all...