# Check spelling taking forever

Tags: texmaker, spelling, grammar

I think it gets applied only for the current page. Anyway, the document has 2 pages. It get's stuck at 11%, why? What can I do to use this nice tool, called "Check spelling"?

[image]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236667/how-to-check-misspelled-words-using-texmaker

Comment: This is an editor specific problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo what do you mean? Maybe you could say more in an answer?  Ruben, thanks for the link!

Comment: There are many different editors which can be used with LaTeX files, and each has a different spell checker.  If you specify which editor you use maybe someone who uses the same editor can help.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am using Tex maker, I thought it was shown from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just closed the spelling checker window (that would take forever) and then just clicked on the spell checker again and it worked.